# How to setup Karma runner code coverage?

Tags: karma-runner

I am attempting to get Karma runner to generate cobertura formatted code coverage reports during a Jenkins build.  I can get it to generate a coverage.xml file, but it does not actually have any coverage data.  It appears (using `LOG_DEBUG`) that the coverage preprocessor is not running.

The relevant pieces from my `karma.conf.js` file are:

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  'app/components/angular/angular.js',
  'app/components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'tmp/scripts/**/*.js',
  'tmp/spec/**/*.js'
];

preprocessors = {
  'tmp/scripts/**/*.js': 'coverage'
};

// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress', 'junit'
reporters = ['dots', 'junit', 'coverage'];

junitReporter = {
  outputFile: 'test-results.xml'
};

coverageReporter = {
  type: 'cobertura',
  dir: 'coverage/',
  file: 'coverage.xml'
};
```

(The junit report is generating fine.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently the [karma code coverage documentation](http://karma-runner.github.com/0.8/config/coverage.html) was more literal than I thought.  Changing my `preprocessors` configuration to

```
preprocessors = {
  '**/tmp/scripts/**/*.js': 'coverage'
};
```

(notice the preceding `**/`) did the trick.  I am not sure why the syntax is different for the `files` array and the `preprocessors` object (`'tmp/scripts/**/*.js'` vs. `'**/tmp/scripts/**/*.js'`).

Comment: thank you! This confused me as well as I just copy & pasted from the files array in karma.conf.js.

Comment: Protip: Karma's preprocessor use minimatch for expression matching. There is an online tester for writing your own pattern here: http://www.globtester.com