# Wrong coverage report in karma

Tags: karma-runner, istanbul

I've configured my **karma.conf.js** with enabled preprocessing to get a report about the code coverage of my tests. I've added this line to the **preprocessors** section.

```
preprocessors: {
  'public/js/app.js': ['coverage'],
  'public/js/filters.js': ['coverage'],
  'public/js/directives.js': ['coverage'],
  'public/js/services/*.js': ['coverage'],
  'public/js/controllers/*.js': ['coverage'],
},
```

What I'm get is a report that is totally wrong. I know that I've written tests for each modules and the function within. But the coverage report shows me only the tests for the services correctly.

For instance the tests for directives. I know that I've written some tests and the tests will also be executed. But the report shows me that I've just tests for 36% of my code lines.

[image: Coverage Report]

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Update:

I see this output from the spec reporter:

```
Directives:
      bsTooltip:
          when the element was created:
                PASSED  - should call the popup function
      bsSwitchtext:
          when the model isBusy changes to true:
                PASSED  - should call the button method with loading
          when the model isBusy changes to false changes:
                PASSED  - should call the button method with loading
```

So I think that my test will all be executed.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there's issue with Typescript & Jasmine which is used by Angular. Enabling source map for test build appears to fix this issue.

I enabled source map in Angular 6.1 as follows,

Go to `angular.json` and in main project, find `test`, and add `sourceMap:true` to enable source map for the test run.

to enable that in CLI, run with command `--source-map` or `--sm=true`

Github issue links

1. [Code coverage report issue with branch coverage (if path not taken)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9451)
2. [ng test --code-coverage in 6.1 improperly detecting branches](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11672)

---

I'm obligated to write this answer as I had the same issue, and this was the first question on Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `console.log('testing123');` at one of the points which shows as not covered. If it shows up when you run the tests you know that something is going wrong with Istanbul.

However my guess would be that either there is something wrong with your configuration, and those tests are not running at al, or the tests are not executing the code as you think they are.

Comment: I've test it before I've posted this here. All my tests will be executed from karma and I think that all test are correct and test this what I'm thinking that it should testing.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing what you have in preprocessors to:

```
preprocessors: {
  '**/public/js/**/*.js': ['coverage']
},
```

I was not able to the report to work unless I followed the specific syntax with **/ before directors in the preprocessors object.

[The karma-coverage documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html) includes the preceding **/ before directories listed in preprocessors.

Based on [this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648775/how-to-setup-karma-runner-code-coverage/15648776#15648776)