# Is there a plugin for karma that highlights Javascript code covered (or not covered) by the jasmine tests

Tags: javascript, php, phpunit, tdd, karma-jasmine

I am about to start developing an application using a mixture of JavaScript and PHP in PhpStorm.

I want to develop in a BDD or TDD way, ideally against an MVC framework.

I have managed to get PhPStorm, PhpUnit and the coverage plugin from Zsolt Takacs to play nicely for the PHP development.

I have Jasmine and karma playing along ok for the JavaScript development but although I have done a lot of searching on this forum and the net in general I can't find an equivalent plug-in for karma.

I checked out a few other unit test frameworks and the only one that looked as if it might offer this was Mocha, but I like the Jasmine style.

Does anyone know of a PhpStorm/karma plug-in that will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you tried using Istanbul? Here's a few links that should help you get up and running

http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-coverage

This also might help:

[How to setup Karma runner code coverage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15648775/how-to-setup-karma-runner-code-coverage)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  As it happens I already had been to those places.  All these talk about coverage reports that show % coverage whereas what I am seeking is something that adds highlights in the actual code.

Comment: you can set karma up to create html files that outline the actual content in the code that has been covered."Configure the reporter
    coverageReporter: {
      type : 'html',
      dir : 'coverage/'
    }
  });"

Comment: Thanks  Ciaran - I will try that as soon as i get back to this issue.

Comment: Thanks @ciaran-george I already had that configured.  What I am seeking is something that adds highlights in the actual code.

Comment: Sorry Andy i'm unsure of anything that does this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that mocha and Istanbul together or mocha and blanket offer exactly the code coverage reporting I am looking for. Jasmine and blanket also appear to do so but I have moved away from using jasmine because I want to use selenium for the user testing and also jasmine does not play as well with requirjs as I would like.